# What are the prizes for completeing the Thunder Dragon's challenges?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After you heal Lanayru, the Thunder Dragon, he offers you two mini-games: a boss rush mode, and a time trial for each of the Silent Realms.

What are the rewards for completing each of these mini-games?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the challenges, there are 4 different types of things you could possibly win.

First of all the two most obvious things, **Rupees** and (mostly) rare **Treasure**.  You can win these in either the **Silent Realm** challenges or the boss battles.  Other things you could win in boss battle mode include a **Piece of Heart** after beating 4 bosses and the **Hylian Shield** after 8 bosses.

Here's the prizes you win if you stop in the boss rush:

1. 20 Rupees
2. Small Treasure
3. 100 Rupees
4. **Piece of Heart** (200 Rupees if you already received this prize)
5. 300 Rupees
6. Rare Treasure
7. 500 Rupees
8. **Hylian Shield** (1000 Rupees if you already received this prize)
9. 2000 Rupees
10. 3 Rare Treasures
11. 3000 Rupees
12. 9900 Rupees (Only possible in Hero Mode, since you won't have the option to fight Demise otherwise)

Comment: p.s., After a number of tries, I was able to verify this personally in my quest for the Hylian Shield.

Answer (score -4):

Piece of Heart (200 Rupees if you received this prize)